# PHP Mysql tracking visitors scalability

Tags: php, mysql, scalability, analytics

I have a web application that runs multiple websites from one codebase. I have it setup with a table that contains the sites and domains that run on the application. The application tracks visitors so we can tell how much traffic we are getting per site and on a global basis for the application.

The problem I am running into is that the visitor tracking is super slow now that there are 2.5 million records in there. Running a query to get the number of visitors this month is taking multiple minutes, making our data not so accessible.

The system is recording the tracking directly from the base php file that includes all the other files. It creates a record in the visitors table when it doesn't find an existing identifying cookie. When it creates the record it assigns a cookie to the user so that when they come back they are only creating the single visitor record. That visitor record stores how many pages they viewed and which page they came into ( entry page ) and the last page they looked at ( exit page ).

We get a fair amount of traffic and I'd like to make this report of monthly visitors accessible by speeding up the results.

I have tried adding an index to the site_id and dates before, but it didn't seem to help speed up things much...

We decided to track analytics ourselves instead of using a tool like google analytics so that we would be able to create some more meaningful data with it later. Such as when a user who is viewing the site submits a contact form and becomes a contact in the CRM we like to see the history of that contact to see which pages they viewed before asking for support, etc.

Any suggestions? The table schema is below. Thanks much in advance, I've been banging my head against the wall trying to come up with solutions.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `analytics_track_visits` (
    `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`site_id` int(4) unsigned default NULL

    ,`inc` bigint unsigned default NULL
    ,`referer` text NOT NULL
    ,`refer_host` text NOT NULL
    ,`user_agent` text NOT NULL
    ,`browser` text NOT NULL
    ,`os` text NOT NULL
    ,`search_term` text NOT NULL

    ,`entry_page` int(4) unsigned default NULL
    ,`entry_page_url` text default NULL
    ,`exit_page` int(4) unsigned default NULL
    ,`exit_page_url` text default NULL

    ,`created` datetime NOT NULL
    ,`created_ip` varchar(200) NOT NULL default ''
    ,`created_user_id` int(4) unsigned default NULL
    ,`modified` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00'
    ,`modified_user_id` int(4) unsigned default NULL

    ,PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
    ,CONSTRAINT `analytics_track_visits__site` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) 
        REFERENCES `site` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT `analytics_track_visits__entry_page` FOREIGN KEY (`entry_page`) 
        REFERENCES `page` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ,CONSTRAINT `analytics_track_visits__exit_page` FOREIGN KEY (`exit_page`) 
        REFERENCES `page` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

`inc` stores the number of pages viewed by that specific visitor. `entry_page` is a foreign key to our cms page table ( same with exit_page ). `browser` and `os` hold values interpreted from the `user_agent`. `search_term` stores any keyword that was used to find the entry page. `site_id` relates to a table containing the list of site settings with doman names.

I have a suspicion that part of the problem is that the table never really gets a break, so when we run a report there are active queries inserting and updating this table at the same time.

Comment: You can get all of this data from analysing your web server's log files... why add all this overhead?

Comment: Even better than log files, use google analytics.  It has an API so you can build any custom reports that you may need.

Comment: the data goes a lot deeper as far as what we want to get from recording this. The web app itself has a lot of different areas of functionality, eventually we'd like to do things such as: a user hits live chat, and we can then instantly show the last 20 pages and actions of a user. Or tracking to see where a specific CRM contact has viewed on the site. It's hard to gleem the data of relationships for things like products, page ids, chat sessions, from analyzing server logs. I have considered it though for general site stats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what kind of queries you're running on it, there are a few things you might want to consider:

- Create a separate table for each site; I know that doesn't seem like a wonderful solution, but it removes the need for another expensive index in your table.
- Set up a read-only slave to do your reporting queries on; this reduces the stress on your main database.
- I believe that InnoDB creates an index for all your foreign keys as well; this doesn't help with the size of your table (it slows down inserts as well). Unless you remove pages regularly, you could do without those.

I'll add more hints if I can think of more.

Comment: thanks, i'm running report queries such as select count(*) as row_count from analytics_track_visits where site_id = 10 and created between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and '2012-01-30 00:00:00'

Comment: @Mike Would you say that your queries would all have `site_id` and a date range? If so, you could introduce a composite index over `site_id` and `created` to make use of range queries. I'm just not exactly sure in which order to create the index :)

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'd say 90% of the report queries are going to have site_id and a date range. Some won't have a site_id as we do some global reporting, however most will have a date range because looking at all the visitors for any date wouldn't be too useful unless we were looking for an all time figure. I guess I will have to try some different combinations of indexes and see what might work best, so far it's been fairly unfruitful

Comment: @Mike you can use `EXPLAIN` syntax to get a better understanding why your query is slow btw.

Comment: I've considered separating the sites out by different tables or databases, but I'd like to have my cake and eat it too.... in being able to query the entire set and get aggregated visitor data for the entire app. Also other systems may go to use the data and want to query visitors for CRM contacts, so having different tables would introduce additional logic to those areas to first decide which table to use before quering visitors by contact

Comment: Those are the joys of scalable design ;-)

Answer (score 1):

2.5 million records isn't that large of a table. I have a log table(recording actions, sign in, sign out, price changes, etc) that is more than 25 million records.

If you query by `site_id` and `created` (just the date portion), I would suggest creating a created_date of type date and a index like: `INDEX (idx_lookup (site_id, created_date)` That should give you the best possible index I believe.

Comment: yeah, 2.5 million isn't much, client wants to see the analytics screen loading in no more than 5 seconds, currently it loads in about a minute or two. I figure there has to be a better way to get this to load faster, or perhaps I'm stuck with throwing hardware at it. I'll play with the indexes a bit and see if that helps.

Comment: if an index doesn't help, better hardware will probably be the only other choice. Start with more memory.